# How to check transferfrom and burnfrom function in remix?

Tags: remix

I am creating simple ERC20 token which involves functions like

`transfer
burn
totalsupply
transferFrom
burnFrom`

How can I check function `transferFrom` and `burnFrom` from remix browser because it involves approve and allowance and whenever I run these function I am getting error .
Here is my contract

```

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4.21;

contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}


contract MyFirsttoken is ERC20Interface {

    address public owner;
    uint256 totalsupply;
    string tokenname;
    string tokensymbol;
    uint8 decimal;

    event Burn(address,uint256 amount);

    mapping(address=>uint256)public balances;
    mapping(address =>mapping(address=>uint256)) internal allowed;

    function MyFirsttoken(uint256 tokensupply, string symbol, string name){

    owner = msg.sender;
    totalsupply = tokensupply;
    tokenname =   name;  
    tokensymbol = symbol;    
    balances[owner] = totalsupply;
    }

    function totalSupply() public constant returns(uint){
        return totalsupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenholder)public constant returns(uint256 balance){
        return balances[tokenholder];
    }

    function transfer(address tos,uint amount) public returns(bool)  {
    require(amount <= balances[msg.sender]);
    balances[msg.sender]-= amount;
    balances[tos] +=amount;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender,tos,amount);   
    }    


    function transferFrom(address from, address to ,uint256 tokens)public returns (bool success){
        uint256 allowedbalance = allowance(from ,to);
        require(tokens <= allowedbalance);
        balances[from] -= tokens;
        balances[to] += tokens;
        emit Transfer(from,to,tokens);
    }

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns(uint){
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender,uint256 amount) public returns(bool success){
        allowed[msg.sender][spender]=amount;
        emit Approval(msg.sender,spender,amount);
    }


    function burnabletoken(uint256 burnableamount)returns (bool){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        require(balances[msg.sender]>=burnableamount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= burnableamount ;
        totalsupply -= burnableamount;
        emit Burn(msg.sender,burnableamount);


    }


    function burnfrom(address from , uint256 burnableamount){

        require(balances[from] >= burnableamount);
        require(burnableamount <= allowed[from][msg.sender]);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] -= burnableamount;
        balances[from] -= burnableamount;
        totalsupply -= burnableamount;
        emit Burn(from,burnableamount);

    }

}
```

```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `transferFrom()` you first have to call `approve()`.

Let's say you have users A and B

- User A approves user B

  ```
  token.approve(B, 1000, { from: A })
  ```
- User B now is able to access up to 1000 tokens from A and transfer them to C

  ```
  token.transferFrom(A, C, 500, { from: B })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your functions `transfer`, `transferFrom`, `approve`, `burnabletoken` are not returning any value but these functions are expected to return `bool`. Also consider the order of execution as mentioned by @ismael in above answer.

Hope it will solve the issue.